# adb shell om clear com.android.vending Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-inapp-purchase

I'm currently testing the Android In-App Billing v3 Library. Everything works as expected, but if I want to reset the Billing Options by following terminal comamnd:

```
adb shell om clear com.android.vending
```

I got the following error:

```
/system/bin/sh: om: inaccessible or not found
```

I'm using a Samsung A51 as real test device

Does someone know what this error means or what could be a different way to reset it?

Answer (score 0):

It means there is no executable command called `om` in the system.

I think what you were trying to do was call `pm` (package manager). 
This would be the equivalent of tapping "Clear data" in settings.

But I am pretty sure clearing data for the Play Store (which is what you are trying to do) will not reset billing for an app.

I recommend you read Google documentation for testing billing:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing